Declaring variable inside or outside of loop
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                     
                                                                                           
int main()                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                  
    int num;                                                                                                                       
    printf("Enter number :-");                                                                                                     
    scanf("%d" , &num);                                                                                                            
    int D = 2 ;                                                                                                                    
    while(D > 1)                                                                                                                   
    {                                                                                                                              
        int denom ;                                                                                                                
        denom = (num%D);                                                                                                           
        if(denom == 0)                                                                                                             
        {                                                                                                                          
            break;                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                          
        D++;                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                              
    printf("GCD of your input is %d" , D);                                                                                         
}

What this program is all about?
Basically, I am trying to divide the user input by an already stored number. If the remainder (denom) is 0 then the loop will break and the printf call will be executed. Otherwise, the already stored number will be increased by 1, and the process continues until the remainder is 0.
What is my problem?
My problem is that if I declare num inside the loop then I get an error saying "num undeclared". If I declare it before the loop then the program works perfectly.
Why is this happening?

It's hard to read your code without proper formatting, but in general, a local variable defined in a loop block (or any other code block within {}) is only "visible" inside that code block, and is "re-created" (logically speaking) every iteration.

Do you mean that scanf("%d" , &num); gives an error about num not being declared if you put int num; inside the loop instead of before the scanf statement?

You have to define int num before you use it in scanf("%d" , &num);

{ begins a "scope". Any variable you declare in this scope will "go out of scope" at the matching }. After that - it doesn't exist anymore. { int x = 1; } printf("%d\n", x); // error

Please provide a [mre] for both, the working code and the non-working code. That will make easier to understand what you describe and explain why the difference is important.

About GCD, you might like to see this implementation of Euclid's Algorithm.

@that other guy             Yes, that what i am taking about.

Aside: int D = 2; while(D > 1) ... D++; makes no sense.

@Weather Vane   Yes, you are right there is no need for condition in while, thanks for correcting.

@Weather Vane   Since i am new to programming stuff. i know how postfix ++ works. but this is something i cannot understand, Can you please explain it more simply.

My point was that the end condition will never be met. And note that GCD works from two inputs, the greatest divisor of both. You seem to be looking for the smallest factor.

@Weather Vane    Yeah sorry about that misleading GCD term ,  i realised it after posting.

Side note: it appears that where you wrote "denominator", the term you were looking for was "remainder".  A "denominator" is a divisor or factor, especially in the sense of the number below the line in fraction notation.  That was among the things I changed in my edit, though I did not reame variable denom in your code.

C identifiers are valid from the point they were defined (or declared) to the end of the enclosing block. Something like the "drawing" below.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{                                          // valid identifiers
    int num;                               // num enclosing block  |
    printf("Enter number :-");             // num                  |
    scanf("%d" , &num);                    // num                  |
    int D = 2 ;                            // num D                |
    while(D > 1)                           // num D                |
    {                                      // num D                |
        int denom ;                        // num D denom  |       |
        denom = (num%D);                   // num D denom  |       |
        if(denom == 0)                     // num D denom  |       |
        {                                  // num D denom  |       |
            break;                         // num D denom  |       |
        }                                  // num D denom  |       |
        D++;                               // num D denom  |       |
    }                                      // num   <------/       |
    printf("GCD of your input is %d" , D); // num                  |
}                                          // <--------------------/

